# C++ and ncurses - stop key press from interrupting key hold

Tags: c++, keyboard

I am using C++ and ncurses to get key input for a game. I have a moveable object that the arrow keys control. The behavior that I want is to be able to constantly move right with an arrow key and jump with the up keyy without interrupting the moving right. However, currently with ncurses, when <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> is being held and <kbd>UP</kbd> is pressed, it stops registering that <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> is being held, and you have to release and press <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> again.

How can I fix this? 
I have seen [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/144558/key-released-multiple-keys-how-to-go-around-ncurses-limitations/144966#144966?newreg=7ac5f49169b145fea916e0aa78e30b32), which is how I'm getting the multiple key input (see below), however I don't think this is the problem.

```cpp
while (gameRunning) {
    int ch;
    vector<int> keys;
    while ((ch == getch()) != ERR) {
        keys.push_back(ch);
        // keys vector now has all pressed keys,
        // however if you are holding right and up is pressed,
        // holding right is not recognized until you release and
        // right is pressed again
    }

    // loop through keys vector here, do things with pressed keys
}
```

Comment: I think there's no solution using getch. You will probably have to use something else or even another more OS-specific library. At least on windows, key repeatition is handled by the OS.

Comment: It's out-of-scope for ncurses, off in the ream of system-specific features.

Comment: Disappointing, I'm going to have to do this another way then